# Is pitchblende the same as Uraninite?

Tags: nomenclature, geochemistry

Different websites say different things on the matter.

**For example:**

[This Website](http://chemistry.about.com/od/chemistrystudentfaqs/f/What-Is-Pitchblende.htm)   Holds that pitchblende is also known by the name Uraninite.

[This Website](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pitchblende)   Holds that pitchblende is a type of Uraninite.

My question is, which website is correct? I have always known the first site to be a reputable source, so I assume that this is a contentious topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you search online for Uraninite then you find various websites saying that uraninite is called pitchblende.

On wikipedia you find :

> Uraninite is a radioactive, uranium-rich mineral and ore with a
>   chemical composition that is largely UO2, but also contains UO3 and
>   oxides of lead, thorium, and rare earth elements. It is most commonly
>   known as pitchblende

even the word pitchblende will automatically redirect you to the uraninite wikipedia page .

Another trustworthy website is mindat.org : uraninite information can be found on this link:http://www.mindat.org/min-4102.html (It seems that there are various names associated to the mineral):

> Re-named in 1845 by Wilhelm Karl von Haidinger for its composition
>   containing uranium. Originally recognized before the element uranium
>   was known and called "schwarz beck-erz" by Franz Ernst Brückmann in
>   1727. Subsequently described with several names including "pseudogalena" and "pitch-like zinc-blende" by Johan Gottschalk
>   Wallerius (Vallerius) in 1747. Named pechblende by Axel Cronstedt in
>   1758. Named "uranerz" by Martin Klaproth after he discovered the element uranium in this mineral. Many spelling variations of the above
>   names known.